# PHP SimpleXML and XSD Type

Tags: php, xml, xsd

I am working with a REST service providing a WADL and XSD's, using PHP SimpleXML.

How can I use the values from enumerations in the XSD's, for example:

XML

```
<condition>MINT_CONDITION</condition>
```

XSD

```
<xs:enumeration value="MINT_CONDITION">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">mint condition</xs:documentation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="de-DE">Neuwertig</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:enumeration>
```

so I could get "Neuwertig" for `<condition>` in code? Applying a stylesheet to render the values as HTML would not help here.

Comment: I do not see what should prevent you to create an annotation reader returning the annotation in the specified language for a given enumeration value. AFAIK XSD is XML so all you need is an XML parser, don't you?

Comment: BTW: It makes not much sense on Stackoverflow to ask if something is possible, because most certainly the answer is *"yes, probably"*. And then it's answered, but it's not helping anybody. Neither you as you ask nor future visitors. So better explain what you're trying to do and why suggested ways to do it didn't made it for you. You can as well related to existing Q&A on this website and explain what and why something didn't work for you.

Comment: Point taken - turned "if" into "how". And thanks for your suggestion, I'm going to try it. Just that the XSD is huge (400 KB) so I am a bit worried about performance, I probably shouldn't use a DOM parser.

Comment: 400 KB is actually nothing for a DOM parser. You worry about unlaid eggs (don't know how that is framed in english properly, you probably guess what I mean :) ). let me know if you need some hints to get this started.

Comment: Thanks again, 400 KB is really nothing, but I store it locally, as downloading it really takes a moment. I am using SimpleXML and XPath, it is quite simple and works fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT: Get enumeration from xsd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833764/xslt-get-enumeration-from-xsd)

Comment: @hakre Could you make your initial comment an answer? Applying a stylesheet as suggested in the possible duplicate is not a solution here but your suggestion should work. Besides, the question is not relevant for me any more and since it is not popular at all it could also be deleted?