# How to access <xs:documentation><xs:enumeration> from XSD File for an XML element (eg Country Code,State Code)

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, enumeration

Problem DeFinition:

I have an XML file and its XSD file
Many Elements in XML have values like :

RES

instead of "RES" I need to display  values from The documentation.

```
<xs:element name="ResidentialStatus">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>
                        RES - Resident
                        NRI - Non Resident
                        NOR - Resident but not Ordinarily resident
                    </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="nonEmptyString">
                        <xs:enumeration value="RES" />
                        <xs:enumeration value="NRI" />
                        <xs:enumeration value="NOR" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
```

One option is to maintain this  Key Value collection somewhere within XSL and use it. But if its directly accessible from XSD, that will be the best option as there are many such elements and maintaining dictionary will be tedious.

Thanks

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Hi Kimbert, I have an XML and need to create a PDF from it. I will  generate an .XSL File which will get data from XML.  few data in XML are referencing ENUMS from XSD file. I tried Code snippets from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52652446/get-enum-value-from-string-using-xslt-and-xsd   This is the exact requirement I have.  I will do  XML-XSL-PDF conversion in .NET using FONET library